# how to disable https on wso2-emm

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot, wso2-identity-server

when I entered 
http://192.168.1.133:9763/emm 
in the brweser I was redirected to 
https://192.168.1.133:9443/emm 
and some resources were not loaded
e.g.

```
<script src="../assets/jqueryext/ui/jquery-ui-min.js"></script>

<script src="../assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

with this error log

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

whic https related I think so
how can I disable https I tried editing
\emm\repository\conf\tomcat\

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
            port="9443"
            bindOnInit="false"
            sslProtocol="TLS"
            maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
            acceptorThreadCount="2"
            maxThreads="250"
            minSpareThreads="50"
            disableUploadTimeout="false"
            enableLookups="false"
            connectionUploadTimeout="120000"
            maxKeepAliveRequests="200"
            acceptCount="200"
            server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
            clientAuth="false"
            compression="on"
            scheme="http"
            secure="false"
            SSLEnabled="false"
            compressionMinSize="2048"
            noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
            compressableMimeType="text/html,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript,application/xml,text/css,application/xslt+xml,text/xsl,image/gif,image/jpg,image/jpeg"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

but the browser redirect to empty page now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know wso1-emm but seems to be a Tomcat server.

Did you try a common http connector definition ?

```
<!-- 
     Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

- [tomcat7 connector doc.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)